# MongoDB query to find most recently added object in an array within a document then making a further query based on that result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two collections in MongoDB; users & challenges.

The structure of the users collection looks like this:

```
name: "John Doe"
email: "john@doe.com"
progress: [
        {
         _id : ObjectId("610be25ae20ce4872b814b24")
         challenge: ObjectId("60f9629edd16a8943d2cab9b")
         completed: true
         date_completed: 2021-08-06T12:15:32.129+00:00
        }
        {
         _id : ObjectId("611be24ae32ce4772b814b32")
         challenge: ObjectId("60g6723efd44a6941l2cab81")
         completed: true
         date_completed: 2021-08-07T12:15:32.129+00:00
        }
]
date: 2021-08-05T13:06:34.129+00:00
```

The structure of the challenges collection looks like this:

```
_id: ObjectId("610be25ae20ce4872b814b24")
section_no: 1
section_name: "Print Statements"
challenge_no: 1
challenge_name: "Hello World!"
default_code: "public class Main {public static void main(String[] args) {}}"
solution: "Hello World!"
```

What I want to be able to do is find the most recent entry in a particular user's 'progress' array within the users collection and based on that result I want to query the challenges collection to find the next challenge for that user.

So say the most recent challenge entry in that user's 'progress' array is...

```
        {
         _id : ObjectId("611be24ae32ce4772b814b32")
         challenge: ObjectId("60g6723efd44a6941l2cab81")
         completed: true
         date_completed: 2021-08-07T12:15:32.129+00:00
        }
```

...which is Section 1 Challenge 2. I want to be able to query the challenges collection to return Section 1 Challenge 3, and if that doesn't exist then return Section 2 Challenge 1.

Apologies if this is worded poorly, I am fairly new to MongoDb and unsure of how to create complex queries in it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach:

```
[
  { // Unwind all arrays
    "$unwind":"$progress"
  },
  { // Sort in descending order all documents
    "$sort":{
      "progress.date_completed":-1
    }
  },
  { // Group them together again but pick only the most recent array element
    "$group":{
      "_id":"$_id",
      "latestProgress":{
        "$first":"$progress"
      }
    }
  },
  { // Join with other collection
    "$lookup":{
      "from":"challenges",
      "localField":"latestProgress.challenge",
      "foreignField":"challenge",
      "as":"Progress"
    }
  },
  { // Only pick the first array element (since there will be just one)
    "$set":{
      "Progress":{
        "$first":"$Progress"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I have provided a comment for each stage so that it would be easier to understand the idea. I'm not confident it's the best approach but it does work since I have tested.

Just a note that there could be a case where `Progress` field is missing. In that case there is no such challenge document.